# Python `sh` module does not recognize pattern matching

Tags: python

For some reason, when I run something like:

```
$ du -sh /some/regex.*/over?/here.txt
```

it gives the correct answer, correctly going through the subdirectories and returning an answer.

Strangely enough, using the `sh` module in python, I run the same command:

```
import sh
print(sh.du("-sh", "rsync_perf/d*/xa*"))
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rzhang2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1427, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/home/rzhang2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 774, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/home/rzhang2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/rzhang2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/du -sh rsync_perf/d*/xa*

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
/usr/bin/du: cannot access 'rsync_perf/d*/xa*': No such file or directory
```

It is also not a relative vs. absolute path issue:

```
print(sh.du("-sh", "/home/rzhang2/secdata/analysis/rsync_perf/d*/xa*"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rzhang2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1427, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/home/rzhang2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 774, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/home/rzhang2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/rzhang2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/du -sh /home/rzhang2/secdata/analysis/rsync_perf/d*/xa*

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
/usr/bin/du: cannot access '/home/rzhang2/secdata/analysis/rsync_perf/d*/xa*': No such file or directory
```

Note: Running either versions in bash in the same directory gives me the answer I wanted.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for this third-party module to see if it even claims to handle bash-style globs as arguments the same way bash does?

Comment: I think this is just bash expanding your glob pattern. Try prefixing the bash command with `echo` to see what arguments are actually being passed to `du`. You can use Python's `glob` module for the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation for this module](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/faq.html#why-doesn-t-work-as-a-command-argument), it doesn't claim to support bash-style glob expressions the same way bash does. In fact, it doesn't support globs at all:

> Glob expansion is a feature of a shell, like Bash, and is performed by the shell before passing the results to the program to be exec’d. Because sh is not a shell, but rather tool to execute programs directly, we do not handle glob expansion like a shell would.
>
> So in order to use `"*"` like you would on the commandline, pass it into `glob.glob()` first:

```
import sh
import glob
sh.ls(glob.glob("*.py"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been cursed with the misfortune of having many pages(including github pages) blocked at work for security reasons, and so I apologize if it was a fairly stupid question. I'll keep the question open in case some stranger chances upon the same problem though. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @OneRaynyDay Your work lets you install packages off PyPI, but doesn't let you look up the documentation on how to use those packages properly? That's a very odd definition of "security". (Not that I'd be too surprised; I've worked with IT people like that in the past…)

Comment: I use an internal anaconda. :)

Comment: @OneRaynyDay OK, not _quite_ as weird. And I suppose blocking docs on Github while allowing SO is a nice way to make sure you copy and paste snippets of code from some random guy instead of code samples from the team that wrote the library…